# add a Variable to end of

Tags: android, variables, android-intent

i have a varible

```
address = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

what can i add this address to end of this line after R.raw in place of HERE

```
 myvid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.HERE));
```

Comment: Why you not check it yourself .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as:

```
address = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

String strUri = "android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+ "/" + "raw/"+address;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(strUri);
myvid.setVideoURI(uri);
```